# Chapter without numeration

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

I am writing my thesis. How can I add the chapter of Introduction without number?

I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}

\input introduction   
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

It works but the problem is that in the table of content it shows **Introduction** in page 3 while it starts in page 1.
[image]

Anybody knows why?

Comment: I think that you are using `\section{introduction}` in your `introduction.tex` file. Use `\section*{introduction}` instead to ignore the regular numeration of the chapters. Then use the `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: @Sina I am using 
\chapter*{Introduction}

Comment: Can you please leave an MWE so that I can run your code?

Comment: Please tell us what's in `introduction.tex`.

Comment: @sina unfortunately I do not get what you mean. I have page of latex as \chapter*{introdution}. 
Then I call it in the original file as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Mico 
\chapter*{Introduction}

Comment: That's all that's in the file? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mico You mean all the things that are in the file of Introduction?!!
It is a long text! If you still think it helps I will send some part of it.

Comment: @Majid - I had asked a simple question (what's in the file), and you gave a rather incomplete (and, frankly, misleading) initial answer. How are people supposed to figure out for you what's going on under such circumstances?

Comment: @Mico I apologize for such an inconvenience. You asked me what is in the file and I though you meant the command that I have in the file of introduction. The only command that I have is \chapter*{introduction}. Then some text about my work. I still do not know what you mean by "what is in the file". The point is that I have a text file and then I addressed the chapter in it. In each chapter the only command is \chapter{chapi}. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to page numbering. You should probably use roman numbers for your first pages and use Arabic numbers from where you really start your thesis. If so, you can use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands. The pages after the first command and before the second command will be numbered with lowercase Roman numerals. Then, `\mainmatter` will restart the page counter and change the style to Arabic numbers.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\lipsum[1-3]

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} 
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{My research plan}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapter{Methodology}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}
```

Which creates the following table of contents:

[image]

Comment: I am exactly using \frontmatter and \mainmatter commands. 
My latex cannot find \usepackage{lipsum} and so I cannot use the comments \lipsum

Comment: I try to put a picture of the text

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from `\chapter*` being executing at the start of your `introduction.tex`, yet you only issue the `\addcontentsline` *after* the entire `introduction.tex` has been read in.

The following code attempts to circumvent all of this by redefining `\chapter` in such a way that it will issue `\addcontentsline` at the appropriate time so your ToC entries are correct.

The redefinition of `\chapter` allows you to use the starred version together with an optional argument as well as a mandatory one. The optional argument will be used for the ToC entry, even if you use it with `\chapter*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

% Create a dummy introduction.tex
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\begin{filecontents*}{introduction.tex}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \chapter*
      \oldchapter*{#3}%
      \IfValueTF{#2}
        {% \chapter*[.]{..}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}%
        }{% \chapter*{..}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#3}%
        }%
    }{% \chapter
      \IfValueTF{#2}
        {% \chapter[.]{..}
        \oldchapter[#2]{#3}%
        }{% \chapter{..}
        \oldchapter{#3}%
        }%
    }%
}
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{%
  \let\chapter\oldchapter
  \oldtableofcontents
}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\input{introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added the command that you mentioned and it just replaced my introduction with something strange!!!!!

Comment: @Majid: I did write in my comments that I *create* a "dummy `introduction.tex`" for use in my example. Did that overwrite your `introduction.tex`? Hopefully not...

Comment: Yes it did :)))
But fortunately I had a backup!

Comment: @Majid: Did my code solve your problem?

Comment: Not completely. I mean a new problem appears. Now it is in page 1 in the table of content. But it is counted as a single page. I mean it is counted like 1-2, 1-2, 1-2
Problem must be something else. I try to see which command is not correct!

Comment: @Majid: It would be best if you could post a minimal example that can replicate the problem. That way we can help you better.

Comment: The problem was solved! I just replaced the command 
\input introduction   
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} 
with  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} 
\include{introduction}

Comment: @Majid: It may be better to use `\clearpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} \input{introduction}`. The `\clearpage` ensures that the ToC entry matches the actual chapter setting.